# Passar mais de um parâmetro na rota Angular

Tags: angular, angular-6, angular-routes

Tenho uma aplicação que utiliza angular v6, tenho um sistema de rotas aonde consigo passar um parâmetro, afim de acessar outro componente, um id por exemplo, porém, necessito passar dois parâmetros nessa rota que atualmente está:

```
{ path: 'edit/:id', component: ProfilesEditComponent }
```

Com a chamada para essa rota configurada assim:

```
private edit(item: IProfiles): void {
         this.router.navigate([`/profiles/${this.appId}/edit`, item.id]);
}
```

Com a minha necessidade de passar dois parâmetros para a rota, gostaria de algo parecido com isso:

```
{ path: ':appId/edit/:id', component: ProfilesEditComponent }
```

Após realizar a alteração na rota, fiz a seguinte chamada:

```
private edit(item: IProfiles): void {
    this.router.navigate([`/profiles`, this.appId, 'edit', item.id]);
}
```

Contudo, não funciona, no console diz que não foi possível encontrar uma rota configurada.

É possível passar mais de um parâmetro dentro da rota? Pois com apenas um parâmetro ele funciona normalmente.

Comment: Acredito que o trecho "tentei a chamada para esse componente assim..." está duplicado, pois esta não parece ser a chamada.

Comment: Acabei me atrapalhando na hora do copiar e colar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível passar mais de um parâmetro sim. Não achei na documentação oficial, mas acredito que vc não pode começar seu path com uma variável (no seu caso 'appId').
Tente alterar a ordem no path:

`{ path: 'edit/:appId/:id', component: ProfilesEditComponent }`

Alterando a ordem também na chamada:

```
private edit(item: IProfiles): void {
    this.router.navigate([`/profiles/edit`, this.appId, item.id]);
}
```